# how to test abstracted functions in javascript using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have 2 javascript A and B functions defined as below and are exposed via another function called API as shown below, I want to test function A to see if it is calling B or not.

```
function A () {
  B()
}

function B () {
  console.log('B is called')
}

export function API (){
  return {
    a: A,
    b: B
  }
}
```

The way i have tried my test functions are as below which do not work.

```
import { API } from './actions-beta'

describe('test A', () => {
  test('', () => {
    const fn = API()
    console.log(fn)
    const spy = jest.spyOn(fn, 'b')
    fn.a()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to test if `B` is called the way the code is written.

### Details

`jest.spyOn` [replaces the function property on the object with a spy](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e41f0bb257c6652c3100b97a1087f9f812fbea0d/packages/jest-mock/src/index.js#L781-L787).

`jest.spyOn(fn, 'b')` will replace the `b` property on the object `fn` with a spy.

`fn.a()` calls `A` which calls `B` directly, it does not call `fn.b` so the spy is never called.

### Solution

`A` needs to call `B` *using an object property that can be replaced with a spy during the test*.

When creating a spy, the *object is typically the module*.

This is why spying on exported functions is quite easy and spying on non-exported functions is quite difficult, which brings up an important point: *if a function calls a non-exported function within the same module then it is just an implementation detail that is not visible outside of the module and with a black box testing approach it does not need to be tested.*

If you find that `B` is more than an implementation detail and you want to spy or stub its functionality then the easiest approach (especially for this code where the export is a function that creates a new object every time it is invoked) is to move `B` into its own module:

---

actions-beta.js

```js
import { B } from './lib';

export function A () {
  B()
}

export function API (){
  return {
    a: A,
    b: B
  }
}
```

---

lib.js

```js
export function B () {
  console.log('B is called')
}
```

---

The test:

```js
import { API } from './actions-beta'
import * as lib from './lib';   // import the module with B

describe('test A', () => {
  test('', () => {
    const fn = API()
    console.log(fn)
    const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'B')   // spy on B using its module
    fn.a()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()   // SUCCESS
  })
})
```